# 502 Error When Deploying Vue+Flask app on Heroku

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app onto heroku with docker using this article:
https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-flask-to-heroku-with-docker-and-gitlab/

I made a simple one page UI using Vue and I'm using Flask for my backend component. When I create the docker image and run it locally, it works. However, when I try and push that image to heroku, I get the 502 errors for the backed endpoints. The UI is visible, but none of the backend endpoints return data.

For example, when I check the console for the deployed version of my app, I get this error messages for every endpoint I try and reach (<my-app> is a substitute for my real app name):

`GET https://<my-app>.herokuapp.com/start/patients 502 (Bad Gateway)`

Below are all the files that I think are relevent.

My nginx file called default.conf file is below (taken from the article and altered to use location /start):

```
server {
  listen $PORT;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  location /start {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

An example of part of my app.py is shown below:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

# instantiate the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# enable CORS
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})

@app.route('/start/patients', methods=['GET'])
def patients():
    #Some code that builds the reponse dict for to return
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
    # Also tried this below
    # app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

My index.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Start from '../components/Start.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Start',
      component: Start,
    },
  ],
});
```

And this is a part of my Start.vue file:

```
<!-- html stuff goes here -->
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from "vue"

export default {
    name: "Start",
    //Other stuff goes here
    methods: {
      getPatients(){
          const path = '/start/patients';
          axios.get(path)
          .then ((res) => { 
              this.patients = res.data.patients;
          }) 
          .catch ((err) => {
              console.error(err);
          });
      },
    }
}
```

This is my main.js:

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Dockerfile (copied exactly from the article):

```
# build
FROM node:15.7.0-alpine3.10 as build-vue
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY ./client/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./client .
RUN npm run build

# production
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache python3 && \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
    if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
    rm -r /root/.cache
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
COPY --from=build-vue /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./server/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn
COPY ./server .
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --daemon && \
      sed -i -e 's/$PORT/'"$PORT"'/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I tried to change the path in my Start.vue file first. When I kept the localhost path ('http://localhost:5000/start/patients'), I noticed that the deployed version of my app on Heroku would hit the endpoint and retrieve data since my local app.py was running on my computer. Changing the path to what was mentioned in the article ('/start/patients') led to the 502 issue.

I also tried and alter the nginx file (default.conf) proxy_pass to the app link (https://.herokuapp.com), but that caused the Heroku app to not deploy.

Here is part of the log output as well (<my-app> is a substitute for my real app name):

> 2023-04-13T17:38:12.774474+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023/04/13 17:38:12 [error] 15#15: *68 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.x.xx.xx, server: , request: "GET /start/patients HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/start/patients", host: "my-app.herokuapp.com", referrer: "https://my-app.herokuapp.com/"

Otherwise, I did not have another idea on how to fix this problem. I figured it is an nginx problem, but I am not sure what is causing the issue exactly.